# How to get ResourceId of VM script is running on in Azure with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure

I am writing a script to setup alerts in Azure, which I'd like to run through a Custom Script extension in Azure, still one of the parameters required to run `Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule` is `TargetResourceId` which is the ResourceId of the VM where the alert should be configured.

So now I wonder - how to get ResourceId of the current VM with PowerShell?

Everything I tried assumes that I have a ResourceName or I iterate over list of VMs in subscription, while what I am interested in is the specific instance on which the script is running.

Comment: Looks like it's not a feature yet (but there are probably workarounds): https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6204911-provide-virtual-machine-instance-metadata-support

Comment: @MarkWragg awesome, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you put it as answer instead of as a comment? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure has an [instance metadata service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service) similar to to those provided by AWS/GCE. You should be able to perform the following:

**CURL:**

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-11-01"
```

**PowerShell:**

```
(Invoke-RestMethod "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-11-01" -Headers @{Metadata = $true})
```

From the server to get instance metadata.

Note that with the PowerShell example above `Invoke-RestMethod` converts the JSON response into a PowerShell object type automatically.

This feature was requested/discussed here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6204911-provide-virtual-machine-instance-metadata-support

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, you could use the following command to get VM's resource id.

```
(get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName shuihv -Name shui).id
```

Also, you also could structure the id if you know VM's resource group name and VM name. Format should be like below:

```
/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<group name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vm name>
```

Update:

As said, you could use [Azure metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service) to get VM's name. According VM's name, you could use Azure PowerShell to get VM's resource group name.

```
 $vm=get-azurermvm |Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "shui"}

$vm.ResourceGroupName
```

Then you could structure resource id.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned in the question - I agree that when you know the ResourceName of the VM - getting ResourceId is easy. But what if ResourceName is not known?

Comment: @LechMigdal As Mark Wragg said, you could use `curl -H Metadata:True "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-04-02&format=json" | jq .` to get VM's name and other information, but currently, you could not use it get VM's resource group name. If possible, you could use a loop to get VM's resource group name according to VM's name.
`